# combination of numbers from different groups

Tags: c#, math

I have 5 groups each having 4 different numbers; I want to make all possible combinations (each having 4 numbers) such that 2 numbers are selected from one group and rest of the numbers (one each) from remaining groups. I have searched at lot of places and have successfully written code to select combinations from 1 group but struggling to find solution to above scenario.
Can anyone give some pointers on this? Thanks for the help!

input:-

```
Group 1: 1,2,3,4
Group 2: 7,8,9,10
Group 3: 15,16,17,18
Group 4: 22,23,24,25
Group 5: 27,28,29,30
```

Expected output:-

```
1,2,7,15 (2 numbers from group 1 and 1 each from group 2 and 3)
7,8,1,22 (2 numbers from group 2 and 1 each from group 1 and 4)
```

and so on...

Below is my code:-

```
private static bool NextCombination(IList<int> num, int n, int k)
      {
         bool finished;

         var changed = finished = false;

         if (k <= 0) return false;

         for (var i = k - 1; !finished && !changed; i--)
         {
            if (num[i] < n - 1 - (k - 1) + i)
            {
               num[i]++;

               if (i < k - 1)
                  for (var j = i + 1; j < k; j++)
                     num[j] = num[j - 1] + 1;
               changed = true;
            }
            finished = i == 0;
         }


     return changed;
  }

  private static IEnumerable Combinations<T>(IEnumerable<T> elements, int k)
  {
     var elem = elements.ToArray();
     var size = elem.Length;

     if (k > size) yield break;

     var numbers = new int[k];

     for (var i = 0; i < k; i++)
        numbers[i] = i;

     do
     {
        yield return numbers.Select(n => elem[n]);
     } while (NextCombination(numbers, size, k));
  }


  private static void Main()
  {
     const int k = 3;
     var n = new[] {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};

     Console.Write("n: " );
     foreach (var item in n)
     {
        Console.Write("{0} ", item);
     }
     Console.WriteLine();
     Console.WriteLine("k: {0}", k);
     Console.WriteLine();

     foreach (IEnumerable<string> i in Combinations(n, k))
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", i));
  }
}
```

Comment: Solution to every problem is not available online. You neee to think thru logically and attempt to write code. Make debugger your friend and take its help to understand how your code behaves. Ever on after that you have issues you come back here with the code and the issue explained properly

Comment: @fubo added my code

Comment: Show some examples also

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya chill buddy..i am not asking for he solution or code; what i want to get suggestion on what would be logic to go about this problem? if you don't have any its fine

Comment: can you please mention what is you expected output?

Comment: Where are these groups in your code?

Comment: @Jamiec all possible combinations, that means all combinations formed will have at least 2 numbers from each group, so its not random

Comment: and groups may have different lengths or same?

Comment: @MukeshModhvadiya same length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a piece of code that does what seems to be required:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    class SelectedGroups<T>
    {
        public readonly IList<T> Choose2; // group to Chose 2 elements from
        public readonly IList<T> Choose1_1; // first group to Chose 1 element from
        public readonly IList<T> Choose1_2; // second group to Chose 1 element from

        public SelectedGroups(IList<T> choose2, IList<T> choose11, IList<T> choose12)
        {
            Choose2 = choose2;
            Choose1_1 = choose11;
            Choose1_2 = choose12;
        }
    }

    static IEnumerable<SelectedGroups<T>> ChooseGroups211<T>(IList<IList<T>> groups)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < groups.Count; i++)
        {
            var outer = groups[i];
            for (var j = 0; j < groups.Count - 1; j++)
            {
                if (i == j)
                    continue;
                var first = groups[j];
                // start from j+1 so  k > j so groups[k] and groups[j] cover all the groups pairs excactly once
                for (var k = j + 1; k < groups.Count; k++) 
                {
                    if (i == k)
                        continue;
                    yield return new SelectedGroups<T>(outer, first, groups[k]); ;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class SelectionResult<T>
    {
        public readonly T Value11; // first value from the group #1
        public readonly T Value12; // second value from the group #1
        public readonly T Value3; // value from the group #2
        public readonly T Value4; // value from the group #3


        public SelectionResult(T value11, T value12, T value3, T value4)
        {
            Value11 = value11;
            Value12 = value12;
            Value3 = value3;
            Value4 = value4;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}", Value11, Value12, Value3, Value4);
        }
    }

    static IEnumerable<SelectionResult<T>> Select211FromGroups<T>(SelectedGroups<T> groups)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < groups.Choose2.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            var value11 = groups.Choose2[i];
            // start from i+1 so  j > i so groups.Choose2[i] and groups.Choose2[j] cover all the pairs excactly once
            for (var j = i + 1; j < groups.Choose2.Count; j++)
            {
                var value12 = groups.Choose2[j];
                foreach (var value3 in groups.Choose1_1)
                {
                    foreach (var value4 in groups.Choose1_2)
                    {
                        yield return new SelectionResult<T>(value11, value12, value3, value4);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<SelectionResult<T>> Select211<T>(IList<IList<T>> groups)
    {
        return ChooseGroups211(groups).SelectMany(g => Select211FromGroups(g));
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //PrintHex(4);
        List<int> g1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        List<int> g2 = new List<int>() { 7, 8, 9, 10 };
        List<int> g3 = new List<int>() { 15, 16, 17, 18 };
        List<int> g4 = new List<int>() { 22, 23, 24, 25 };
        List<int> g5 = new List<int>() { 27, 28, 29, 30 };

        var allGroups = new List<IList<int>>() { g1, g2, g3, g4, g5 };

        foreach (var selectionResult in Select211(allGroups))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(selectionResult);
        }
    }
}
```

See [online demo](http://rextester.com/JLEEA59553).

The idea behind the code is following:

1. First select from all groups 3 to choose elements from. I.e. generate an `IEnumerable` of all such `SelectedGroups`. This is done by the method `ChooseGroups211`. An important point here is that `Choose1_1` and `Choose1_2` are totally symmetrical so you want to select only of of two pairs `(Gi, Gj)` and `(Gj, Gi)`.
2. From each fixed `SelectedGroups` produce all the combinations of 4 elements (`SelectionResult<T>`). This is done by the method `Select211FromGroups`. Again `Value11` and `Value12` are symmetrical so you want to select only one of two pairs.
3. Use [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx) to join those building blocks into a method that does what you want - `Select211`.

**Notes**: This code is pretty straightforward but at the same time it is pretty much hardcoded for this specific task i.e. selection of exactly 4 elements as 2 + 1 + 1. This allowed me to use named types instead of `IEnumerable<T>` for the results and intermediate results which I generally prefer. If requirements were different, I'd probably used generic `IEnumerable` or an array `T[]` and some more advanced tricks like [Computing a Cartesian product with LINQ](https://ericlippert.com/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq/)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much..you saved the day. Smart solution.